# Let $f$ be entire such that $f(x+ix)\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. If $f(2)=1-i$, find $f(2i)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be entire such that $f(x+ix)\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. If $f(2)=1-i$, find $f(2i)$.

So far, I have that since f is entire , $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^n(2)(z-2)^n/n!=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^n(2i)(z-2i)^n/n!$. So $f(2+2i)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^n(2)(2)^n i^n/n!=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^n(2i)(2)^n/n!=a\in \mathbb{R}$. I'm not sure if this is heading in the right direction.

Comment: Since you know $f(2+2i)\in\mathbb R$, you don't have to worry about non-real terms, and by equating parts, you may deduce even more.

Answer (score 5):

Consider $g(z)=f(z(1+i))$; then, for real $x$, $g(x)=f(x+ix)$ is real, which means that
$$
g(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nz^n
$$
with $a_n$ real, because $g^{(n)}(x)$ is real for real $x$. In particular,
$$
g(\bar{z})=\overline{g(z)}
$$
(overlining means conjugation). Now
$$
f(2i)=f\bigl(i(1-i)(1+i)\bigr)=g\bigl(i(1-i)\bigr)=g(1+i)=
\overline{g(1-i)}=\overline{f\bigl((1-i)(1+i)\bigr)}=\overline{f(2)}
$$

Comment: I was thinking it in a completely different way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- if $L=\{x+ix:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$, prove that $f(L)=\mathbb{R}$. (Use connection arguments)
- Note that the line by $2$ and $2i$ is perpendicular to $L$.
- Prove that $f$ is conform